# How do I hide the navbar (or collapse to hamburger) on my website when scrolling on small devices? [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css

TL/DR; title says it all. HTML/CSS only website not performing as desired.

I'm an absolute beginner with HTML/CSS having only done an online University of Michigan HTML and CSS course 5 years ago. I've written my small business page using a W3 CSS template but have issues when viewing on small devices in particular. We don't need a really fancy javascript website to attract customers from competitors.

I've made a copy of the website (stripping out all personal details) and uploaded it to http://testurl.gq (not sure if linking to a site is allowed?) I just didn't want to post my entire code here.

I've tried to hide the navbar when scrolling because it takes up too much screen on a mobile device but have had no luck - it should be easy, right? How do I hide it, or make the font shrink so it reduced consimed screen real estate?

Also, the text for each person is hidden on mobile devices by default, but is there an easy way to show it by clicking on the photo of the individual?

Thanks for taking the time to read and respond. If it's preferable to paste my html and css file contents let me know and I'll upload it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp)

```
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("myNavbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myNavbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried a script based on that page, and even inserted the one above, but neither have worked. I'm wondering whether there's some code there stopping the behaviour?

Comment: you must remove `window.onscroll` in your codes `window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};`. you don't need to `function myFunction(){}` too.